# Retrival of Apex code with line numbers

Tags: apex

Need help to retrieve code from other apex classes in my apex class.

I was able to do this via the query below:

```
select body,bodyCrc,LengthWithoutComments from apexclass where name='AccountHandler'
```

But the problem is, the code is retrieved as a string without line numbers.

Any suggestions on how  to retrieve the same with line numbers.

Comment: You'd think you could split on `'\n'`, but they seem to be stripped out.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Wasn't a problem for me using execute anonymous.

Comment: I guess the query editor just strips them out. @Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the line numbers back in yourself using e.g.:

```
apexclass ac = [select body from apexclass where name='AccountHandler'];
String[] lines = ac.body.split('\n');
String[] numberedLines = new String[] {};
for (Integer i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    numberedLines.add((i + 1) + ': ' + lines[i]);
}
String numbered = String.join(numberedLines, '\n');
System.debug(numbered);
```

(Best to pad the numbers to a fixed width.)